# rotate gradient in DrawingBrush in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a drawingBrush defined and I want to rotate the gradient. The below does not work as it is rotated out of the object frame. How do I rotate this to the center of the object?

```
    <DrawingBrush x:Key="SteelBrush_Vert" Stretch="Fill">
    <DrawingBrush.Drawing RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
        <DrawingGroup>
            <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M114.000,293.847C114.000,280.324,114.045,269.362,114.100,269.362L391.900,269.362C391.955,269.362,392.000,280.324,392.000,293.847L392.000,485.878C392.000,499.400,391.955,510.362,391.900,510.362L114.100,510.362C114.045,510.362,114.000,499.400,114.000,485.878z">
                <GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="114,389.862" EndPoint="392,389.862" MappingMode="Absolute" SpreadMethod="Pad">
                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFDADADA" Offset="0.082" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF282828" Offset="0.854" />
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.949" />
                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </GeometryDrawing.Brush>
            </GeometryDrawing>
        </DrawingGroup>
    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
    <DrawingBrush.RelativeTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
    </DrawingBrush.RelativeTransform>
</DrawingBrush>
```

Comment: What do I set them to? I tried 0 for both and it does not work

Comment: What is the sense of the GeometryDrawing? The Geometry seems to be just a rectangle. You could easily replace the DrawingBrush by a LinearGradientBrush with appropriate start and end points that make it vertical.

Comment: It's a geometric design, LineraGradientBrush doesn't cut it

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer with guess and check

```
   <DrawingBrush x:Key="SteelBrush_Vert" Stretch="Fill">
    <DrawingBrush.Drawing RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
        <DrawingGroup>
            <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M114.000,293.847C114.000,280.324,114.045,269.362,114.100,269.362L391.900,269.362C391.955,269.362,392.000,280.324,392.000,293.847L392.000,485.878C392.000,499.400,391.955,510.362,391.900,510.362L114.100,510.362C114.045,510.362,114.000,499.400,114.000,485.878z">
                <GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="114,389.862" EndPoint="392,389.862" MappingMode="Absolute" SpreadMethod="Pad">
                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFDADADA" Offset="0.082" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF282828" Offset="0.854" />
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.949" />
                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </GeometryDrawing.Brush>
            </GeometryDrawing>
        </DrawingGroup>
    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
    <DrawingBrush.RelativeTransform>
        <RotateTransform CenterX=".5" CenterY=".5" Angle="90"/>
    </DrawingBrush.RelativeTransform>
</DrawingBrush>
```